# Blender registers random amount of characters when I press keys on keyboard

Tags: shortcut

Whenever I press a key (eg. typing numbers for rotation and etc.) Blender types random amount of the character that I typed. For example if I press the F key just a single time, it'd type "ffffff".Also when I press hotkeys it does the same thing, eg. when I press Ctrl+Z it applies multiple times and the same for all other hotkeys! I searched everything I could but didn't find anything about this problem.

I tried reinstalling but didn't work.

I'm using windows 10 and Blender 2.93.3

Comment: Are you sure your keyboard isn't to blame?

Comment: Absolutely. I tried Microsoft's touch keyboard and the same thing happened and as you can see I'm typing here with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Arduino leonardo board and it's plugged in all the time(I use it for my flight sim). I simply unplugged it when using Blender and it works perfectly fine now.